# Literal alternative in Python

Tags: python

According to [this doc](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#implementation),

> Importing those from typing is deprecated. Due to PEP 563 and the intention to minimize the runtime impact of typing, this deprecation will not generate DeprecationWarnings. Instead, type checkers may warn about such deprecated usage when the target version of the checked program is signalled to be Python 3.9 or newer. It’s recommended to allow for those warnings to be silenced on a project-wide basis.

I tried to use literal type without using `typing.Literal` like the following

```py
def foo(flag: bool) -> "hello" | "hi": # <- error
    return "hello" if flag else "hi"
```

I used `|` because python supports `str | int`, however, I got syntax error with literal.

How can I declare multiple literal type?

Comment: There's a list of specific `typing` objects which are deprecated and replaced with alternatives. `Literal` is not among them. I.e., keep using `typing.Literal`.

Comment: I overlooked the part in doc. Thank you, @deceze.

Answer (score -1):

You can only use `|` (union) on `typing.Literal` for literal unions.

The reason `str | int` works is because those classes define an equivalent of `__or__`, on the class itself (the metaclass) which returns a `types.UnionType`. It is not define the same on the instance (i.e. there's a difference between `class | class` and `instance | instance`).